# Determine GPIB primary/secondary addresses using GPIB commands

Tags: gpib

How do I determine the General Purpose Interface Bus primary/secondary addresses using General Purpose Interface Bus commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what addresses are in use on the bus you can send an unlisten.  Then send an address to listen for each address on the bus, monitoring for the NDAC going low. You have to unlisten each device. The 488.2 spec has a command look for all Devices. There is also the 488.2 command *STB? To get the status byte from each instrument. But that requires all instruments to conform to 488.2. A serial poll with a check for each device then check the status byte.

The secondary addresses are private to each device. They are not necessarily addresses. They may be device specific commands.  You’ll need the manuals.